# Have the Rebels ever insulted the Imperials the way that the Imperials insult them?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

During the ground assault on the forest moon of Endor an Imperial officer captures Han Solo and his group of rebels he famously says the line:

> You Rebel scum!

It is quite clear that the Empire did not hold the Rebel Alliance in high regard. My question is, have the Rebels ever insulted the Imperials in a similar way?

Comment: I'm asking this so next time I play X-Wing against my friends I have a comeback to the shout of "Rebel scum!" that our gaming session was liberally scattered with.

Comment: Nazis, genocidal maniacs, xenophobic lunatics and the list goes on and on... But no I dont think that Rebels ever did insult Imps that way

Comment: I remember a Corellian calling an Imperial officer a "bootlicker" during X-Wing Alliance. That's all I've got.

Comment: I've though about this for the exact same reasons since I prefer to play rebels in X-Wing Miniatures. The best thing I could come up with was "Imperial Pigs", but I don't think that has any canon occurrences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**CANON:** From Wookieepedia's [List of phrases and slang](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang):

- "Bucket head" - Many rebels [called](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Buckethead) imperial stormtroopers "bucket heads"

  > EZRA: And you bucketheads are gonna to be sorry
- "Bucket brain" is also used for stormtroopers
- "Emperor's snowmen" - stormtroopers
- "Imp" - a slang, possibly derogatory term for an Imperial
- "Plasteel pig" - stormtrooper
- "Stifftroopers stormbloopers" - stormtroopers
- "target practice" - stormtroopers

Many of these were coined by Ezra Bridger in *Star Wars: Rebels*, which shows the early days of the Rebellion. Ezra is what you might call a main Rebel, as he is the show's main protagonist. Insults he comes up with are therefore technically Rebel insults for imperials. It's also possible that these insult could still catch on and become even more commonly used among the Rebellion as the show progresses.

Comment: Honestly, bucketheads and Imps are the only two terms that are used at a wide enough scale to be considered something the Rebellion uses regularly. Anything Ezra invents can't really be counted, imo, unless we know it's been adopted by the Rebellion at large. I've always thought Imps are an abbreviation rather than intended to be derogatory though.

Comment: @thegreatjedi *Rebels* shows the early days of the rebellion, and Ezra is a main rebel, so insults he comes up with are technically rebel insults for imperials. The OP didn't say it had to be widespread or extremely common. Ezra's nicknames could also still catch on and become commonly used as the show progresses.

Comment: Well, in the OP's case I guess he may be looking at specific instances. To me, as a "seasoned" fan, it's just that the term Rebel scum is used so frequently by Imperials the galaxy over that I interpreted the question to imply it's looking at Rebel equivalents: the context is insults used in common practice at an institutional level, lol

Comment: The Mandalorian shows that "Imp" has continued as a insult.

Comment: Diminution of names is generally considered insulting or at least patronizing, so "Imps" makes sense. As for Ezra, he's kind of a punk kid... I'm not sure how influential he really is.

Answer (score 1):

**Legends**:
Thoughout the X-Wing series, the TIE model fighters are called by various nicknames, most often used in the Rebel military.

- TIE Fighter: "eyeball"
- TIE Interceptor: "squint"
- TIE bomber: "dupe"
- Hybrid craft: "DIE-Wing", "Uglie" (though these were most often used by anti-rebel pirates)

Answer (score 0):

Well, when Rebels fight Imperials, they are predominantly facing two types of foes:

- Stormtroopers
- TIE Fighters

Stormtroopers are frequently called "bucketheads", a term that originated from the Republican period when clone armor were considered as little better than serving as body buckets - only good for keeping your body in one piece. In the Imperial period, it became a derogatory term as the Empire starts making everyone's lives miserable. Sure, everyone unhappy with the Empire uses it, but as long as Rebels also use it, that counts right?

Notable users (according to Wookieepedia's article on the term):

- Ezra Bridger: once to Stormtroopers guarding his detention cell, second to Agent Kallus (who wears a similar bucket)
- Han Solo: in reference to TIE pilots
- Poe Dameron: in reference to First Order Stormtroopers

I'm sure Rebel pilots have a word for TIE pilots, who literally come in annoying swarms but drop like flies (TIE Fighters are notorious easy to 1-shot), but I can't recall any offhand just yet...